# return which img is onscreen

Tags: javascript, image, typescript

I am trying to determine which image is onscreen for a matching game. I have a console log at the end of the typescript function and have tried multiple different variables (i.e: img, images[] ) but this returns undefined in console log. Any suggests on how to return which image is on screen ? Thanks.

*Also, this is a typescript application using some java script code*

**dashboard.ts**

```
 ngOnInit() {


 //fucntion to randomize and get face images
    var w = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    var button = document.getElementById('randomize');
    var images = w.children; // inner elements, your image divs
    // a function to hide all divs
    var hideDivs = function(imgs: HTMLCollection) {
      for (var img of < any > imgs) {
        (img as HTMLElement).style.display = 'none';

      }
    }
    hideDivs(images); // hide all initially

    button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length); // get random index
      hideDivs(images); // hide all images

      (images[rnd] as HTMLElement).style.display = 'block'; // show random image
      (event.target as HTMLElement).textContent = 'Click one more time!';
      console.log("WANT OUTPUT OF WHICH IMAGE ONSCREEN HERE:" , + );
    })



   }
```

**dashboard.html**

```
   <div id="wrapper" align="center">
  <img class="happy" img src='../../assets/happy.PNG' alt="happy" img id="happy"> 
  <img class="sad" img src='../../assets/sad.PNG' alt="sad" img id="sad">
  <img class="embarrassed" img src='../../assets/embarrassed.PNG' alt="embarrassed" img id="embarrassed">
  <img class="sleepy" img src='../../assets/sleepy.PNG' alt="sleepy" img id="sleepy">
  <img class="stressed" img src='../../assets/stressed.PNG' alt="stressed" img id="stressed">
  <img class="suprised" img src='../../assets/suprised.PNG' alt="suprised" img id="suprised">
  <img class="excited" img src='../../assets/excited.PNG' alt="excited" img id="excited">


</div>
<button id='randomize' onClick = "this.style.visibility= 'hidden';" class="btn btn-success btn-block">START GAME</button>
```

Comment: what kind of information would you like to get for the image displayed? The name of the class for instance?

Comment: either then name of the class or img ID, thanks.

Comment: Please, see my answer below

Comment: what's up with the plus sign? `console.log("WANT OUTPUT OF WHICH IMAGE ONSCREEN HERE:" , + );` ? if you want to log `images[rnd]` then log that, not a random `+` sign...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get images output of the images displayed, you can proceed this way:

```
 button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      ...
      var image = (images[rnd] as HTMLImageElement);
      console.log('src', image.src);
      console.log('class', image.className);
    })
```

Comment: src is returning NaN, class is also returning Nan

Comment: @KatieKennedy, I made a change as regard the type of the image

Comment: @KatieKennedy - It would only return NaN if you're trying to do a mathematical operation on it.. did you remove the plus sign? because it is indeed, Not A Number.

Comment: also thank you @edkeveked, your solution works also when I realized the change. Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try to search for images in  ngAfterViewInit().